# Menu navigation with deeplink in Android

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have an app which including the possibility of deeplinking into a number of different activities. This works great.

My problem is how to navigate back.

When not deeplinking these activities are one or two levels below a menu.
I need the user to be able to navigate back to the menu when he leaves the deeplinked activity and not out of the app.

It would make so sense for the activity to start the menu activity as this is backwards.

The only possibility I can think of is to have the deeplink open the menu and navigate automatically down to the activity I want without user interaction. However this seems to me to be beating the whole idea of deeplinking.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm sure [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#explicit) will give you some more insights

Comment: This is actually just the opposite of what I am looking for. I don't want an empty activity stack

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,
The way that I handled that was implementing the back navigation customized for my scenario.
I was looking for an empty back stack and if the back stack is empty then I navigate to the specific destination that I want to